# Mockobject doesn't return instance of baseclass

Tags: mocking, phpunit

In this function below I want to mock a PDOStatement to give as a parameter to my function loadFromStatement.

```
/**
 * @expectedException ObjectNotFoundException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage Unable to load site
 */
public function testLoadFromStatementThrowsObjectNotFoundException()
{
    $oMockedPDOStatement = $this->getMockBuilder('\PDOStatement')
                                ->setMethods('rowCount')
                                ->getMock();
    $oMockedPDOStatement->expects($this->any())->method('rowCount')->will($this->returnValue(0));
    SubSiteFactory::loadFromStatement($oMockedPDOStatement);
}
```

This is the signature of the function `loadFromStatement`:

```
public static function loadFromStatement(\PDOStatement $oStatement, $aPrefixMap = NULL, $iIndex = NULL)
```

However the `oMockedPDOStatement` returns a `MockObject` which in turn generates an IllegalArgumentException.

Why can't `oMockedPDOStatement` return an instance off PDOStatement?

Comment: Did you tried without the `mockBuilder` ? It returns an instance of the desired class ?

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me. I found the solution. See below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is what goes wrong:

`->setMethods('rowCount')` should be `->setMethods(array('rowCount'))`